# Evernote Android SDK Login OAuthException on production

Tags: android, evernote

I'm working on an app that uses Evernote SDK for Android. I can login and access notes on Sandbox environment, but when I switch to production I get an error. My key was activated on production.
I'm using

> com.evernote:android-sdk:2.0.0-RC4

I've followed the official guide https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android

Should I change

The error is:

```
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '<html>
<head>
<script>
  (function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/IsLoggedIn.action', true);
    request.onload = function() {
      if (this.status === 403) {

        window.location = '/Login.action?targetUrl='
          + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname);
      }
    };
    request.send();
  })();
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="/favicon.ico?v2" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/redesign/global/css/reset.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/redesign/global/css/fonts.css" media="all" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/redesign/global/css/header.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/redesign/global/css/layout.css" />

<title>Evernote Error</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-inner">
      <a href="https://evernote.com/" class="evernote-logo"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="160" height="36" viewBox="0 0 160 36">
  <title>Evernote</title>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-14.89 -14.89)">
    <rect width="189.752" height="65.168" y=".117"/>
    <g fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="translate(14.89 14.89)">
      <g transform="translate(38.54 5.84)">
<path class="evernote-logo-2018-text" d=""/>
          </g>
<path class="evernote-logo-2018-elephant" d=""/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg></a></div>
      </div>
      <div id="container-boundingbox" class="wrapper">
        <div id="container" class="wrapper">
          <div class="main">
<div class="page-header">
              <h1>
                Oops, we encountered an error.</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>
                Sorry, we've encountered an unexpected error.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer wrapper">
          <a href="https://evernote.com/tos/" class="footer-entry">Terms of Service</a><a href="https://evernote.com/privacy/" class="footer-entry">Privacy Policy</a><span class="footer-entry last">Copyright 2018 Evernote Corporation. All rights reserved.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    '
        at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
        at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:64)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:40)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:45)
        at com.evernote.client.android.EvernoteOAuthHelper.createRequestToken(EvernoteOAuthHelper.java:106)
        at com.evernote.client.android.EvernoteOAuthHelper.startAuthorization(EvernoteOAuthHelper.java:127)
        at com.evernote.client.android.login.EvernoteLoginTask.startAuthorization(EvernoteLoginTask.java:144)
        at com.evernote.client.android.login.EvernoteLoginTask.execute(EvernoteLoginTask.java:51)
        at com.evernote.client.android.login.EvernoteLoginTask.execute(EvernoteLoginTask.java:23)
        at net.vrallev.android.task.Task.executeInner(Task.java:67)
        at net.vrallev.android.task.TaskExecutor$TaskRunnable.run(TaskExecutor.java:191)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon the same issue: I have contacted evernote and it turned out the key was not activated on production although I was told it was.